# Manage multiple instances of a process automatically

Tags: process, distributed-computing, process-management

I have a program that takes about 1 second to run and takes a file as input and produces another file as output.  Problem is I have to be able to process about 30 files a second.  The files to process will be available as a queue (implemented over memcached) and don't have to be processed exactly in order, so basically an instance of the program checks out a file to process and does so.  I could use a process manager that automatically launches instances of the program when system resources are available.

At the simple end, "system resources" will simply mean "up to two processes at a time," but if I move to a different machine make this could be 2 or 10 or 100 or whatever.  I could use a utility to handle this, at least.  And at the complex end, I would like to bring up another process whenever CPU is available since these machines will be dedicated.  CPU time seems to be the constraining resource - the program isn't memory intensive.

What tool can accomplish this sort of process management?

Answer (score 0):

Storm - Without knowing more details, I would suggest [Backtype Storm](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki).  But it would probably mean a total rewrite of your current code.  :-)

More details at [Tutorial](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Tutorial), but it basically takes tuples of work and distributed them through a topology of worker nodes.  A "spout" emits work into the topology and a "'bolt" is a step/task in the graph where some bit of work takes place.  When a bolt finish it's work, it emits same/new tuple back into the topology.  Bolts can do work in parallel or series.